# using pandas make a string column into multiple columns with True/False

Tags: python, pandas

I have this:

df = pd.DataFrame({'my_col' : ['red', 'red', 'green']})

```
my_col
red
red
green
```

I want this:
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'red' : [True, True, False], 'green' : [False, False, True]})

```
red  green
True  False
True  False
False   True
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
for color in df['my_col'].unique():
    df[color] = df['my_col'] == color

df2 = df[df['my_col'].unique()]
```

It will loop over each color in `my_col` and adds a column to `df` with the name of the color and True/False whether it is equal to the color. Finally extract `df2` from `df` by selecting only the color columns.

Another option is to start with an empty dataframe for `df2` and immediately add the columns to this dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for color in df['my_col'].unique():
    df2[color] = df['my_col'] == color
```

Output:

```
     red  green
0   True  False
1   True  False
2  False   True
```

Answer (score 1):

Python functionality `get_dummies` can work for this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'my_col': ['red', 'red', 'green']})
new_df = pd.get_dummies(df, dtype=bool)
new_df[:] = np.where(pd.get_dummies(df, dtype=bool), 'True', 'False')

new_df.rename(columns={'my_col_green': 'green', 'my_col_red': 'red'}, inplace=True)
print(new_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the original dataframe is `df`, one can use:

1. [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)
2. [`pandas.Series.str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html)

---

**Option 1**

Using [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html), one can do the following

```
df2 = pd.get_dummies(df['my_col'], dtype=bool)

[Out]:

   green    red
0  False   True
1  False   True
2   True  False
```

If one wants the column `red` to appear first, a one-liner would look like the following

```
df2 = pd.get_dummies(df['my_col'], dtype=bool)[['red', 'green']]

[Out]:

     red  green
0   True  False
1   True  False
2  False   True
```

---

**Option 2**

Using [`pandas.Series.str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html), one can do the following

```
df2 = df['my_col'].str.get_dummies().astype(bool)

[Out]:

   green    red
0  False   True
1  False   True
2   True  False
```

If one wants the column `red` to appear first, a one-liner would look like the following

```
df2 = df['my_col'].str.get_dummies().astype(bool)[['red', 'green']]

[Out]:

     red  green
0   True  False
1   True  False
2  False   True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# reset index, to keep the rows count
df=df.reset_index()

# create a cross tab (don't miss negation for the resultset)
~(pd.crosstab(index=[df['index'],df['my_col']], 
             columns=df['my_col'])
 .reset_index()                  # cleanup to match the output
 .drop(columns=['index','my_col']) # drop unwanted columns
 .rename_axis(columns=None)        # remove axis name
 .astype(bool))                    # make it boolean
```

```
    green   red
0   True    False
1   True    False
2   False   True
```